# fuelphp - The requested view could not be found: template.php

Tags: php, fuelphp

The error is triggered from:
    `C:/wamp/www/bayadko/fuel/core/classes/view.php @ line 440`

This is my `index.php`

```
<?php foreach ($parent as $parent): ?>
    <h3><?php echo Html::anchor('blog/view'.$parent->user_id, $parent->password) ?></h3>
    <p><?php echo $parent->password ?></p>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This is my `blog.php`

```
<?php 
class Controller_Blog extends Controller_Base
{
  public function action_index() {
    $view = View::forge('blog/index');

    $view->parents = Model_Parent::find('all');

    $this->template->title = 'My Blog about Stuff';
    $this->template->content = $view;
  }
}
?>
```

What could be causing this error?

Comment: This is the site I've been working in http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/build-an-admin-panel-with-the-fuel-php-framework--net-23186

Answer (score 0):

Controller_Base extends Controller_Template which uses template.php in the views folder to template out all of the pages in fuelphp for you. This is really helpful as is lets you abstract important things like html or css that's included on every page. All you have to do to resolve this is make a new file in the views folder called template.php. Here is some starter code to get you started on the template.php file.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
    <?php echo Asset::css('bootstrap.css'); ?>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="container">
            <?php echo $title; ?>
        </div>
    </header>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <?php echo $content; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr/>
        <footer>
            <p class="pull-right">Page rendered in {exec_time}s using {mem_usage}mb of memory.</p>
            <p>
                <a href="http://fuelphp.com">FuelPHP</a> is released under the MIT license.<br>
                <small>Version: <?php echo Fuel::VERSION; ?></small>
            </p>
        </footer>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```